# Get presence information from PubNub

Tags: ios, objective-c, pubnub

I am trying to setup a two person chat with PubNub.  I am having trouble differentiating between the clients.

I signed up for Presence in the admin console and have enabled the feature like this:

```
[PubNub subscribeOnChannel:[PNChannel channelWithName:@"my_channel" shouldObservePresence:YES]];
```

I have an observer setup like this:

```
[[PNObservationCenter defaultCenter] addMessageReceiveObserver:self withBlock:^(PNMessage *message) {
           //identification code here
}];
```

I know the `PNMessage` contains the channel and message content but how do I get the `clientIdentifier` of the device that sent a message received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According their docs and iOS SDK repo which is here: https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/tree/master/iOS#publishing-messages

> Messages can be an instance of one of the following classed: NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.

You can send other object types as the message (rather than just a string as you are doing). You can simply send a dictionary object with a senderID key that the subscribers can then read.

Comment: So I modify the send to include the message as well as the object id and then I have to parse the return as JSON?

Comment: If you provide the code you use to actually send the message I can help you restructure it. Also to whoever downvoted this answer, can you provide a reason? This is the correct answer to his question.

Comment: I was able to get this working by sending a dictionary and parsing the return JSON back.  Thank you.  Marked as answer.  Once the code is cleaned up, I will put it into the original post.

Comment: @johncs Did you happen to find time to update the original post? :) Might help other people here including me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an observer for Presence events, here is an example of using addPresenceEventObserver:withBlock:

https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/blob/master/iOS/HOWTO/SimpleSubscribe/PubNubDemo/ViewController.m#L39

to log UUIDs, (also know as the client identifier):

https://github.com/pubnub/objective-c/blob/master/iOS/HOWTO/SimpleSubscribe/PubNubDemo/ViewController.m#L52

Is this what you are trying to do?